# SimpleDateFormat doesn't give me the pattern I need

Tags: java, html, mysql, database, simpledateformat

I'm having a problem with SimpleDateFormat. I have inputfields in my HTML-page with type = date. I want to save these values into my database where they should be saved as dates. I already figured out how to do this and it works. The only probem I encouter is the way the dates are represented in the database.

I want them to be representated as dd-MM-yyyy. Let's say I want to display 01-06-2016 into my database. When doing this with the code I have..it gives me 0006-12-07. Strangely..when I change my pattern into yyyy-MM-dd...it does give me exactly what the pattern says: 2016-06-01. But it doesn't work the other way round.

```
String parameter = request.getParameter("instroomdatum");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
try {
    Date parsed = sdf.parse(parameter);
    java.sql.Date sql = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
    student.setInstroomdatum(sql);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(StudentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Can somebody please explain me what's going on and how to fix this problem? It's really annoying.

**EDIT:** I tried printing the value of     parameter with a simple PrintWriter-object for the specific date 01-06-2016. It shows me 2016-06-01, even though my pattern in the code above is set to dd-MM-yyyy.

Comment: Show us the value of `parameter`

Comment: This value comes from a inputfield which has type date in HTML. It's a calandre where you can choose a date.

Comment: HOW it got its value is immaterial. What is important is what it looks like.  Show an actual sample value.  Without that, nobody can help you.

Comment: I will try printing this value with a simple println and give you the value.

Comment: Alright, I have tried printing this value with a PrintWriter-object and it gives me this date 2016-06-01 when using dd-MM-yyyy. The date I tried to pick was 01-06-2016.

Comment: You should [edit] this information into your question.  Also, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Date-Time != String

As explained in the [correct Answer by Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38040720/642706), you must understand that a date’s value internally in a database or in a language such as Java is distinct is distinct from a String generated to represent or communicate that value.

How the date is internally tracked varies amongst databases and languages, and is irrelevant really. What matters is the interface provided by which you can fetch or put your app’s values. A *separate* issue is how to represent those values as Strings for presentation to your user.

> Database (internal) ↔ Driver ([JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC)) ↔ App ([java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)) ↔ Presentation (String)

## java.time

Also, the Question and the other Answers are using old outmoded classes, the date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Those  classes have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### `LocalDate`

Amongst the java.time classes is [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) to represent a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. The old `java.util.Date` class, despite its unfortunate name, tracks both a date *and* a time-of-day. The old `java.sql.Date` *pretends* to represent a date-only but in fact, in an unfortunate design decision, extends from `java.util.Date` so it inherits both a date and a time-of-day, but you are instructed in the class doc to pretend that it is not a subclass. (yes, that is an unpleasant mess)

Do all your business logic using the java.time classes such as `LocalDate`.

## Strings & ISO 8601

As for strings, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. For serializing date-only values, that means YYYY-MM-DD. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings that represent date-time values.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2016-06-01" );
```

But try to stick with objects. Serialize to strings only when you must.

## Database

No need for strings when getting data to/from a database. The job of a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) is to figure out how to move a Java object to/from a data type of your database column.

With a driver that complies with [JDBC 4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/jdbc_42.html), you should be able to use the `getObject` and `setObject` methods on a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to deal directly with java.time types.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , localDate );
```

If your driver does not support that, you must fall back onto the java.sql.Date class. Look for new methods added to the old classes to go back and forth with java.time types.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( localDate );
```

And the other direction.

```
LocalDate localDate = sqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

## Generate Strings

Apply a format to generate a string as needed for presentation to a user. Use the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. You can define your own formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-yyyy" );
String output = localDate.format( formatter );  // 01-06-2016
```

Better yet, let java.time localize to the human language and cultural norms of the user’s desired/expected [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT , locale );
String output = localDate.format( formatter );
```

You will need to use the formatter to generate a String for presentation to the user, and to parse input made by the user. You or your users may wish instead to take data-entry as three separate fields: year, month, and day-of-month.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 6 , 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpfull!

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the *display format* with the internal representation.

Dates in a database are not *represented* in any specific *display format*, such as `YYYY-MM-DD`.  Database dates are normally stored in a numeric form that represents a certain number of seconds and milliseconds (or nanoseconds) from some fixed starting point.

The display format is applied dynamically when you query the database and ask for the date/time as a string, but if you ask for it as a `Date` object, you get the internal representation, encapsulated in a `java.sql.Date`.

It is up to your Java code to format the date as you need it.

In your particular example (according to your comment), the string returned by your input method is `2016-06-01`, so you need to parse it with the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd`.  This will correctly convert the external representation to a valid `Date` object.

> But how should i specifically change this representation to dd-MM-yyyy

Once you have it as `Date`, you can immediately turn around and convert the `Date` back into a `String` with a different `SimpleDateFormat` specification.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I understand you. But what do you suggest? Should I save my value into a string and pass this string into my database, even though..the column where it will be saved in my database has the type ''date''?

Comment: No, you want to store it as a `Date`.  As I commented above, until you show us a sample of what the input looks like, we can't provide a complete answer.

Comment: But how should i specifically change this representation to dd-MM-yyyy. It's clear to me now that the inputfield give me a string in the format yyyy-MM-dd, but how can I change this to what I want? I tried changing the pattern in the code above to dd-MM-yyyy, but this didn't work as I already said. 

Sorry if I didn't fully understand you. I'm a bit new to this.

Comment: Can you give me a example of this in code so I can follow you better?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is format your date into `01-06-2016` format. Try this

```
String parameter = "0006-12-07";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    Date parsed = sdf.parse(parameter);
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(parsed)); //Prints out your desired format 07-12-0006
    java.sql.Date sql = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
    student.setInstroomdatum(sql);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(StudentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
}
```

Comment: This might work if you try it out for a specific string-date. But I'm trying to do this for all the dates that people pick from that html-calandre. I tried this out, and it didn't work for me. It gives me 2016-06-01

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

java.sql.Date someDate;

Date anotherDate = format.parse(/*needVariables*/.getOutDate());

someDate = new java.sql.Date(anotherDate.getTime());
```

work for me